# Will Instagram blacklist requests?

Tags: instagram

I've been using https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/[tag]/?__a=1 to get a json containing images tagged with [tag] but this stopped working for some reason. The think is I'm still getting results from the URL if I try it in my browser, but at my LAMP server Instagram returns a 404.

Is it possible Instagram is blacklisting traffic from IPs if I exceed a limit? And if yes - will it solve itself or is my server blacklisted forever?

Not really API related but I was hoping someone here have had the same experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really an issue for Instagram support. BTW, are you sure the error isn't a 400 or 429?

Comment: Thank you, and yes I'm sure it's 404. I did find out though that I get the same error if I try curl or wget in terminal.
For me Stackoverflow is an arena where we can discuss problems & share ideas without bothering official support and I'm sorry if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You get an answer from the browser that you are logged on Instagram.

I found the same problem.